# Same field name different data types how to check if empty

Tags: java, lotus-notes

In IBM notes I have a Java agent which checks if the field ActualDelivery date is empty or not:

```
 String ActualDeliveryDate =  orderRegelDocument.getItemValueString("ActualDeliverydate");
 if (ActualDeliveryDate.equals("")  ){
```

But the problem is that this field ActualDeliverydate is set in some documents as a Text field and in some documents as a DateTime field.. So how can I know when it is a text field and then take the string and when to take it as DateTime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the [Item](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESITEM_CLASS_JAVA.html) instead of the item value.

```
Item theItem orderRegelDocument.getFirstItem("ActualDeliverydate");
```

Then check the Item's [Type property](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_TYPE_PROPERTY_ITEM_JAVA.html) and do the conversion if necessary:

```
String ActualDeliveryDate;
if (theItem.getType() == Item.DATETIMES)
{
 DateTime dt = theItem.getDateTimeValue();
 ActualDeliveryDate = dt.getLocalTime();
}
else
{
 ActualDeliveryDate =  orderRegelDocument.getItemValueString("ActualDeliverydate");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aditionally, you could delete empty DateTime and Number fields from documents. In classic Notes development, a simple `@If(@Text(@ThisValue) = ""; @DeleteField; @ThisValue)` in `InputValidation` can do the job.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use IBM notes, but this should work

```
Object actualDeliveryDate = orderRegelDocument.getItemValue("ActualDeliverydate");
if(actualDeliveryDate instanceOf String){
    //compare with a string
}else if(actualDeliveryDate  instanceOf Date){
   //do something else
}
```

I don't know about the actuel object that are used, so just debug it to see it.

Comment: getItemValueString() returns always a string. Use `orderRegelDocument.getItemValue("ActualDeliverydate").elementAt(0)` instead

Comment: `String` is not a `Date` and never will be.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann can I eventually do actualDeliveryDate instanceOf datetime?

Comment: if object is string how to save the actualDeliveryDate object as a String then and idem for DateTime?

Comment: oups, was a bit too fast. 
Of course, it's not getItemValueString but getItemValue.